# Can you get use of arbitrary-precision arithmetic?

Tags: gecode

I am modeling algorithm to hardware mapping with **Gecode** and standard **Gecode::Int::Limits** is too small at least because I want to target systems with more than 2^32 memory.

Is there a way to get use of arbitrary-precision arithmetic with Gecode or at least 64-bits integers?

I know that Gecode can be built with **MPIR** or **GMP** support, but seems those are just for trigonometric operations?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [Gecode documentation](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf) properly:

> The totally available number of bits for all variable implementation types used by Gecode is 32

So seems there is no way to model with values bigger than **2147483646**, but I still think I'm fundamentally wrong about something, since it's almost obligatory for modeling toolkit/library to have an ability to model with values bigger than that. Especially, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECLiPSe) that:

> ECLiPSe interfaces to external solvers, in particular ... and the Gecode solver library

but [ECLiPSe tutorial](http://gki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws1415/csp/csp11.pdf) stands that

> Numbers in ECLiPSe come in several flavors:
>
> - Integers can be as large as fits into memory, e.g.:
>     123 0 -27 393423874981724

I cannot understand how *just* an interface being able to have numbers bigger than underlying library.